# How to use a fact as an equation in latex

Tags: environments

I have `a fact` that I want to use it in my latex as `equation` file it does not look too good. I was wondering if there is any other way to make it and look it better

```
This allows us to use the well known fact that, 

 \begin{myquotenumber}
 \label{eq:cond_uniform}   for a Poisson process $X^0$ independent random variables uniformly distributed on $\textbf{Z}$.
 \end{myquotenumber} 
 
In summary, a simple and convenient choice
```

This is how the figure shows [image: figureShows]

This is used in `mythesis.tex` file

```
\NewEnviron{myquotenumber}{\vspace{3ex}\par
\refstepcounter{equation}%
\hfill\parbox{\dimexpr \textwidth-4cm}%brug \parbox[b] for bunden [c] (standard) for center og [t] for top
{\textrm{\BODY}}
\hfill\llap{(\theequation)}\vspace{2ex}\par}
```

Comment: the image shows that your myquotenumber environment is inserting  unwanted space tokens at the start which is why there is a space before `for`, but as you have shown no code, not easy to offer help Please post a small complete document that makes the image shown.

Comment: Do you have a diagram of how it should look? The question is subjective to taste and what you want to display.

Comment: Please tell us how or where the `myquotenumber` environment is defined.

Comment: I updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be overthinking things with the `myquotenumber` code. Since the facts are supposed to use the same counter as `equation`, I think you might as well place the facts in `\parbox` statements.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\newcommand\myparbox[1]{\parbox{0.667\textwidth}{\raggedright #1}} % choose width suitably

\begin{document} 
This allows us to use the well known fact that
\begin{equation}\label{eq:cond_uniform}   
\myparbox{For a Poisson process $X^0$ independent random 
   variables uniformly distributed on $\textbf{Z}$.}
\end{equation} 
In summary, a simple and convenient choice \dots
\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome!! this looks better and makes space go away. I like that we can control how big the width.